# Download Image from an url in Android

Tags: java, android, bitmap, drawable

I have to download an image from an url. Do you recommend Bitmap or Drawable? Whatever, I have tried twice, but those don't work. Do you know what could be the problem?? (I have written the internet and the external storage permissions). You will see that I recieve the URL by a JSON object, but I was recieved correctly.

If I want to recieve it in a Drawable element:

```
protected Drawable getDrawable()
    {
        try{
            JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(content);
            String src=jsonResponse.getString(data);
            InputStream is = (InputStream)new URL(src).getContent();
            Drawable d=Drawable.createFromStream(is, "basket.png");
            return d;
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            String err="This is the error: ";
            Log.e(err,e.getMessage());
            //e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }
```

If I want to recieve it un a Bitmap element:

```
protected Bitmap getBitMap()
    {
        try{
            JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(content);
            String src=jsonResponse.getString(data);
            java.net.URL url = new java.net.URL(src);
            HttpURLConnection con=(HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
            con.setDoInput(true);
            con.connect();
            InputStream input=con.getInputStream();
            Bitmap myBitmap=BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);
            return myBitmap;
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            String err="This is the error: ";
            Log.e(err,e.getMessage());
            //e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }
```

This is where I have the ImageView:

```
public class Accedido extends AppCompatActivity {

    ImageView imagen;
    Button ok;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_accedido);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        imagen=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.Img);
        ok=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btnOk);
        ok.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Bitmap img=null;
                Ajax im=new Ajax();
                try {
                    String imagen = im.execute(MainActivity.IP_ADDRESS + "Imagen").get();
                    LeerConsulta lec = new LeerConsulta(imagen, "img");
                    //img=lec.getBitMap();
                    /*String res=lec.getContent();
                    String res2=lec.getData();
                    Toast.makeText(Accedido.this, "Content:"+res+"Data:"+res2, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();*/
                    img=lec.getBitMap();
                }
                catch(Exception exc) {
                    Toast.makeText(Accedido.this, exc.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                imagen.setImageBitmap(img);
            }
        });
    }
```

When I run those codes, the program throws me an error which says `println needs a message`...But I have never written in the program a system.out.println

Comment: Do u want to download the image to Storage or on Imageview  ?

Comment: No. I just want to download it and show it in an ImageView

Comment: Please explain, **in detail**, what "those don't work" mean. For example, you could log the stack trace from your exception (which your current code does not do), then include that stack trace in your question.

Comment: @F.Riggio check out my code to download.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use Asynck task to download image .

```
 private class DownloadImageTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {
        ImageView bmImage;

        public DownloadImageTask(ImageView bmImage) {
            this.bmImage = bmImage;
        }
        protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... urls) {
            String urldisplay = urls[0];
            Bitmap mIcon = null;
            try {
                InputStream in = new java.net.URL(urldisplay).openStream();
                mIcon = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return mIcon;
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
            bmImage.setImageBitmap(result);
        }
    }
```

You can refer this link http://www.wingnity.com/blog/android-json-parsing-and-image-loading-tutorial/

Comment: I have just updated the code to show you that I have the ImageView in another class. How can I access to the backGround function in the other class? Please, edit your code for that case

Comment: Is it wrong if I do this in the oher class?
`String imagen = im.execute(MainActivity.IP_ADDRESS + "Imagen").get();
                    LeerConsulta lec = new LeerConsulta(imagen, "img");
                    String src=lec.onPostExecute();
                    img=lec.doInBackground(src);`

Comment: The code from the last commentary didn't work, but I have tried doing the background investigating how could I get the background answer and it worked. Thank you so much!!!

Comment: Happy coding !!

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Glide library](https://github.com/bumptech/glide) to download the image directly from the URL into your image view.

```
Glide.with(context).load(url).diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL).into(imageView);
```

Comment: This is for a project where I should have an apart class for this

Comment: Reinventing the wheel is bad, you'll end up with OOMs

Answer (score 0):

Bitmap is better in my opinion.
Try this out.
Make sure that the URL you get from the JSON is only of image.

```
JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(content);
String src=jsonResponse.getString(data);
java.net.URL url = new java.net.URL(src);
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(url.openConnection().getInputStream());
```

Moreover, Universal Image Loader library is also available. Try that as well.

Comment: I want to download it from this url: http://10.1.1.2:8080/basket.png (I wrote it my phone's browser and I could see that image, so that's okay). It could be possible because the image doesn't have the same size as the ImageView?? I will try what you wrote

Comment: Size will never be problematic.

Comment: I would highly recommend to try Universal Image Loader as well. It is especially designed for this purpose.

Comment: It didn't work. When I try to do it, the program throws me an error which says `println needs a message` but I have never written in the code system.out.println....

Comment: What do you mean with Universal Image Loader @Muhammad Abdullah

Comment: its a library. https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader

Answer (score 0):

Volley is an HTTP library that makes networking for Android apps easier and most importantly, faster. At a high level, you use Volley by creating a RequestQueue and passing it Request objects. The RequestQueue manages worker threads for running the network operations, reading from and writing to the cache, and parsing responses.

You can use `Volley` for Image downloading:

Add repo in your Gradle:

```
compile 'com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0'
```

You need to add this code, in your class where `ImageView` is present, just add the code (In download button if you have any):

```
ImageRequest imageRequest = new ImageRequest(your_image_url, new Response.Listener<Bitmap>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(final Bitmap response) {
                    your_image_view.setImageBitmap(response);
        }
    }, 0, 0, ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_INSIDE, null, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Toast.makeText(your_activity_context.this, error.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });

    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(your_activity_context.this);
    requestQueue.add(imageRequest);
```

Courtesy [Google.com](https://developer.android.com/training/volley/simple.html)

Comment: I have never read about Volley... what's the advantage of using that? I have the function which gives me the image in a class and I have the ImageView in another class....Can you write the code considering that?